# Deep key name conversion while preserving the type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a TypeScript function that converts camel case to snake case. The function should be able to handle both objects and arrays of objects. I want to specify the input and output types as generics. If the input isn't an object or an array of objects, I just want to return the input value untouched.

The issue I'm facing is that since the return type is a union type, TypeScript doesn't know which type is returned when the function is used.

Here's my current implementation:

```js
function deepConvertToSnakeCase<I, O>(item: I): I | O {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        return item.map((el) => deepConvertToSnakeCase(el)) as O;
    }

    if (item !== Object(item)) {
        return item as I;
    }

    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(item as Array<[string, unknown]>).map(([key, value]) => [
            key.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1_$2').toLowerCase(),
            deepConvertToSnakeCase(value)
        ])
    ) as O;
}

// usage

interface CamelCaseObject {
    keyItem: 'value';
    keyItemAlso: 'value';
}

interface SnakeCaseObject {
    key_item: 'value';
    key_item_also: 'value';
}

const data: CamelCaseObject = {
    keyItem: 'value',
    keyItemAlso: 'value'
};

const convertedData = deepConvertToSnakeCase<CamelCaseObject, SnakeCaseObject>(data);

// Result: convertedData type is CamelCaseObject | SnakeCaseObject
// Expected result: convertedData type is SnakeCaseObject
```

Edit: minimal reproducible example
Edit: question edit

Comment: Please include a [mre]. The code you've given so far isn't standalone; I should be able to paste it into the TS playground and not have to make any changes.

Comment: ① Please [edit] the bottom code snippet to be a [mre] of you calling your function without third-party or private code, and the expected i/o types so we can all test it.  ② I'm not sure how you intend to "preserve the type" when all the keys are different; you'd need to write a type mapping function that actually converts keys as well.  It's possible that you're looking for [the code at this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WozdLm).  Is that it? If so, I'll write an answer explaining (but please do [edit] in a [mre] first); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please see prev comment: so you intend to just *tell* the compiler that the output type is `ISomeInterface[]` even if the input has arbitrary unrelated keys?  You can do so then like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAL9vN), but that has obvious problems.  Do you want the compiler to actually understand what the key mapping is doing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks! I've edited the code to a minimal reproducible example. "Preserving the type" wasn't the right way to phrase what I meant, my bad. I just want the function to have a generic type that it then returns like so `deepConvertToCamelCase<T>(item: T | T[]): T | T[]`. It would've worked expect in this case since `item` could be an array, the way I implemented it doesn't work

Comment: But in your example code, the `item` is neither a `ISomeInterface[]` nor a `ISomeInterface[][]`, so I don't see how you'd expect that to work.  Your output type is different from your input type, and I don't see any mention of this in the question.  Do you understand why this is the case? A function that takes an input of type `{a_b: number}` and produces an output of type `{aB: number}` cannot be thought of as being of a type like `(item: T) => T`.  Instead it has to be something like `(item: T) => DeepCamelCase<T>`. I'm not sure if I've managed to convey the issue; can you confirm?

Comment: @jcalz right, I can see what you mean now. In that case you're right, I'll have to write a type mapping function as you've shown in the first playground example

Comment: So should I write my answer up then? Do you want to [edit] the question to acknowledge that the type mapping you're looking for is not really anything like `T | T[] => T | T[]` and change the [mre] to demonstrate the actual desired behavior?  I could do the edit myself if you'd prefer, but I don't want to start on this if my approach doesn't actually meet your needs.  Could you test it and get back to me?

Comment: @jcalz yes, I'll play around a bit then edit my question and the minimal reproducible example to better reflect the desired behaviour. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jcalz sorry, it took me a while. I played around with it and I think I understand now what kind of result I expect. I've edited the question to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: Uh, maybe you're looking for [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGGLJW)?  (Note that `K` implies "key"; the convention isn't "use `K` after `T`", it's "use `K` for keylike types". I changed it to `I` and `O` for Input/Output, which hopefully is more illustrative of your situation.)  If so I could write up an answer, if not, what am I missing now?

Comment: @jcalz yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you! The only thing I don't get is why we have to cast `as any` for every return

Comment: You don't have to assert `as any` but you have to do something, since the compiler can't possibly verify that your return value matches that type.  If you want to write `as I extends readonly any[] ? ⋯` or do something else, that's up to you.  `as any` is the tersest way for me to say we're not trying to type check the return value.  Shall I write up an answer, or is there something we need to resolve about the type assertions (TS has type assertions, not "casts", or at least the word "cast" is ambiguous and generally avoided in TS)?

Comment: @jcalz got it. Yes, please write the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to manually and explicitly specify the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments for `I` and `O` when you call `deepConvertToSnakeCase()`, but you want the return type of the function to be either `I` or `O` (or maybe an array of `O`) depending on what type `I` is.  That means you need the return type to be a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks `I`.  Like this:

```
function deepConvertToSnakeCase<I, O>(item: I):
  I extends readonly any[] ? O[] : I extends object ? O : I {
   /* snip ✂ ⋯ ✂ snip */
}
```

So if `I` is arraylike, your output is an array of `O`.  Otherwise if `I` is objectlike, your output is `O`.  And otherwise, if `I` is a primitive, then your output is `I`.  Which gives callers the behavior you're looking for:

```
const convertedData =
  deepConvertToSnakeCase<CamelCaseObject, SnakeCaseObject>(data);
// const convertedData: SnakeCaseObject

const convertedData2 =
  deepConvertToSnakeCase<string, SnakeCaseObject>("abc");
// const convertedData2: string

const convertedData23 =
  deepConvertToSnakeCase<CamelCaseObject[], SnakeCaseObject>([data]);
// const convertedData23: SnakeCaseObject[]
```

---

Of course the implementation of `deepConvertToSnakeCase()` cannot possibly verify that the output really is of that conditional type.  You'll need to do something like [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) your return values are of the required type. You're already doing that (with `as I` and `as O`) and you'll have to keep doing that with the new return type.  The easiest way is with [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
function deepConvertToSnakeCase<I, O>(item: I):
  I extends readonly any[] ? O[] : I extends object ? O : I {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    return item.map((el) => deepConvertToSnakeCase(el)) as any;
  }
  if (item !== Object(item)) {
    return item as any;
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item as Array<[string, unknown]>).map(([key, value]) => [
      key.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1_$2').toLowerCase(),
      deepConvertToSnakeCase(value)
    ])
  ) as any;
}
```

That addresses the question as asked.  But please beware that this easily allows you to lie to the compiler.  While the input type can be checked against `I`, the compiler has no idea whether or not the implementation of `deepConvertToSnakeCase()` will really produce a value of type `O`.  You can specify any type you want for `O` and the compiler will accept it. Meaning that nothing stops some crazy person from making this call:

```
const nothingStopsThis =
  deepConvertToSnakeCase<{ a: string }, { b: number }>({ a: "" });
// const nothingStopsThis: {b: number};
```

Here someone claims that `{a: ""}` will be converted to a `{b: number}`, and the compiler believes that claim. But of course it doesn't, so bad things can happen at runtime.

It is indeed possible to write a type utility with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to actually *compute* what `O` should be for a given `I`, so that, say, `{abCd: string}` will be converted to `{ab_cd: string}` in the type system.  This would be a lot safer for callers (although the implementation still would need type assertions). This is out of scope for the question as asked so I won't digress further with an implementation of the utility type. The point is: be careful when calling this function not to use an incorrect `O`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&noErrorTruncation=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKaoA4GEEDdUBOUAKnAMpgCGA1qlpQM6oA8AkgDSIDyAfABQwoqALYAuRKwCUogFCIJiVAA8hYZA0QFUlZAgA2AT0SUwBgNoBdRAH5ulxONaKVqNRrgAjAFapoN7g4KAN5yiDDAiHwAggQElAYAdDAMMXEGAkLCkpKIIfLyWlAgBEiCIgnClBh8fKh6OQC8PCjo2HiEJORUtPRMtfU5jMamANyhAL6h4ZFlwogAhA0N3N6+UBki2bmhBahFJWGZxhomBmPyk7v7SFyr0AnABHDCAKJgUAQwqAx8Oys+91cHy+P1mx0QqXizDMDGBYAA5pxwNQwHAAO5gCw8SQVKo1My0AycXCUPQgVAWRrNMx-eSEhJaDB6SgQVB8AD0fDMlAAtAAvSlcqI8gBalPZiMQAHIACQARgA+jKAExSnFQOAAGXRhF6bMk7FpLUwODA+CIpAoNDojDZJLJqEkf0poUGJ1GMkmMnZ7MQIAYlHhqBkMhg70IwBZqEQ9GEdT1twBUG2dNQBlYmXEUvt5Kl50QhIzIiiegYcCzOdQec9IbDQgIkdZiCtPVtibWKYLaYVswrpNz+cJPcyCtJZb7DurXogCFhKEoUEo4lj8bbd2TyzyXfTmellalhtTO+LpfLe-7Vc9YxkM7Ac9v5qEyAAIgvKIgGqE0Cb2hauta9WYFc9ATddOBbG0mHbaB+GQN9JDGH1EFve9fyfV9F3ECDQKTEMUOTB8OlQF832VD8v1aU1H0tbpIJYWFPgRcDaJwtZ+AAIkoDwIHYhDvV9fDkLQ4iMMoZVxAYsN4Tw2cCOEkjF2VABmcj5G-NozQ6GiANtIDKDjEC1yTSxmJ0qD134Mw4MXSlEIE2ShM0ogRNIpSsJYoy1ksGS72TVEoAACyksgNQwBhiCCjRPzUyi0O01smGYIJjAkuF4UQcZOGSjxxDAEBhA8QgMv4ZKl0Qdj2IyvikME-ygoREK4DCiLknEIIcsQPKCsIcYRiAA)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a definition error, in the `deepConvertToCamelCase` function definition, you set the return type to `T | T[]`. Then in your usage, in `findAllMergeRequests`, you define the return type of that is only `IMergeRequestData[]` whereas `deepConvertToCamelCase` returns the type `IMergeRequestData[] | IMergeRequestData[][]`

You have two options with the first one being preferential in my opinion:

1. Have `deepConvertToCamelCase` only return `T`

   - You would need to split the function into two mutual recursion functions that can handle the array functionality that you need. If you don't need access to the array-returning one from outside you could have the definition be nested within the `deepConvertToCamelCase` function.
2. Make `findAllMergeRequests` have the return type of `Promise<IMergeRequestData[] | IMergeRequestData[][]>` and deal with that in the usage of that function